# My CSV file is not registering that I have a string in my code, how can I fix that?

Tags: python

[image]
input:

```
states = ['Michigan', 'California', 'Louisiana']
numbers = ['00','10','00']
```

my input was concatenated by using

```
for x,y in zip(states,numbers):
    print(f'{x},{y}')
```

output:

```
Michigan,00
California,10
Louisiana,00
```

this output was saved as a csv file, however when I open the csv file it shows me this:

```
Michigan 0
California 10
Louisiana 0
```

shows me this in two separate columns, with states in the first column and numbers in the second column. It is not registering that the numbers are a string and need to be together in the numbers column.

It should instead look like this in the csv file:

```
Michigan 00
California 10
Louisiana 00
```

I wrote my data into the csv using:

```
file_data= ""
for x, y in zip(states,numbers):
    file_data += f"{x},{y} \n "
    
#create a new file
with open("states_num.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(file_data)
```

Comment: How do you write data into the csv file?

Comment: Did you try: `print(f'{x},"{y}"')`?

Comment: i updated my question with the code I used to write my data into csv file.

Comment: yes i tried that and it didn't work

Comment: When you say "look like this in the csv file", do you mean looks like that when you open it in Excel (like your image), or when you open it in a text editor like Notepad(++)? Excel interprets the csv, that is not what it realy looks like.

Comment: @NielsHenkens yes when i open the csv

Comment: When you open the csv in the program.....?

Comment: The advice here may help, depending on where you need to open the CSV: https://superuser.com/questions/861964/how-do-i-stop-excel-from-converting-value-0503e000-to-5-03e02-automatically/862073

Comment: You still are not getting my question. If you say "that is what appears, as shown in the image above." then apparently you are judging the Excel VISUALISATION of the CSV, not the actual CONTENTS of the CSV. Look at the answer of OneCricketeer below. Judge if the csv is correct or not by opening it in Notepad++, Notepad of any other texteditor. NOT by opening it in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

> when I open the csv file it shows me this:

Open... In excel? That's not your actual file content since you wrote a comma in your output

There's no type information saved in csv files. Excel therefore decides to read and present data however it can, and you shouldn't rely on a GUI to tell you what's actually in a human readable text file

If you want to save excel files with type information, then don't use a CSV writer

> my lists were converted into a string

You don't need that code since you already have two lists of strings that your zip() loop can use to pair the elements

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in `numbers` (and thus `y`) are integers, `f"{x},{y} \n "` will write them without zero padding.

To write with f-strings and zero-padding, use formatting with a 0-prefix:

```
file_data= ""
for x, y in zip(states,numbers):
    file_data += f"{x},{y:02} \n "
```

where the `2` is the number of places to pad to.

It's also more efficient to collect all lines in a list `lines`, and and `''.join(lines)` in the end instead of using `+=`. `+=` for strings (and `bytes`) is a little tricky in Python, since it does not really mutate the LHS, but rather creates a new string with the LHS and RHS concatenated, and assigns it.

Comment: Are you sure you copied/typed it exactly as stated here?